# Text out of text view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablelayout, android-studio-3.0

I am currently having a problem with Android application. I am using a table layout with some views in it. The problem is that it seems like the `TextView` does not wraps the text correctly. However, when I change swipe between fragments it just resizes and it fits as how its supposed to.

This is what is looks like in the first place when the `onCreate` function is called.

[image]

And this is how it looks when I swipe between fragments.

[image]

This is the method I used to set up the views inside the table.

```
 private void initializeBookTable(final List<Book> bookList, View view, final Button modifyBtn, final Button deleteBtn)
{
    //Get screen width
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    TableLayout table =  view.findViewById(R.id.book_tableLayout);
    //Border for the text views
    final GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTeal));
    gd.setCornerRadius(2);
    gd.setStroke(2, 0xFF000000);
    //Font for the text views
    Typeface font = Typeface.create("casual",Typeface.BOLD);
    //Header row
    TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this.getContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams headerRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    headerRowParams.setMargins(0,1,0,0);
    headerRow.setLayoutParams(headerRowParams);
    //Header name text view
    TextView headerName = new TextView(this.getContext());
    headerName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.book_NAME));
    headerName.setBackground(gd);
    headerName.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
    headerName.setTypeface(font);
    headerName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    headerName.setMinWidth(screenWidth/4);
    headerRow.addView(headerName);
    //Header chapter text view
    TextView headerChapter = new TextView(this.getContext());
    headerChapter.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.book_CHAPTER));
    headerChapter.setBackground(gd);
    headerChapter.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
    headerChapter.setTypeface(font);
    headerChapter.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    headerChapter.setMinWidth(screenWidth/4);
    headerRow.addView(headerChapter);
    //Header page text view
    TextView headerPage = new TextView(this.getContext());
    headerPage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.book_PAGE));
    headerPage.setBackground(gd);
    headerPage.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
    headerPage.setTypeface(font);
    headerPage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    headerPage.setMinWidth(screenWidth/4);
    headerRow.addView(headerPage);
    //Header name text view
    TextView headerStatus = new TextView(this.getContext());
    headerStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.book_STATUS));
    headerStatus.setBackground(gd);
    headerStatus.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
    headerStatus.setTypeface(font);
    headerStatus.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    headerStatus.setMinWidth(screenWidth/4);
    headerRow.addView(headerStatus);
    //Add row to table
    table.addView(headerRow);
    for(int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this.getContext());
        //Set text views parameters
        TableRow.LayoutParams textViewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textViewParams.setMargins(0,1,0,1);
        row.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        //Set text views parameters
        TextView name = new TextView(this.getContext());
        name.setText(bookList.get(i).getName());
        name.setBackground(gd);
        name.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        name.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        TextView chapter = new TextView(this.getContext());
        chapter.setText(bookList.get(i).getChapter());
        chapter.setBackground(gd);
        chapter.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        chapter.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        TextView page = new TextView(this.getContext());
        page.setText(bookList.get(i).getPage());
        page.setBackground(gd);
        page.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        page.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        TextView status = new TextView(this.getContext());
        status.setText(bookList.get(i).getStatus());
        status.setBackground(gd);
        status.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
        status.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        //Add text views to the row
        row.addView(name);
        row.addView(chapter);
        row.addView(page);
        row.addView(status);
        row.setClickable(true);
        //Click listener for each row
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) view;
                selectedRow = tableRow;
                //If the row is already selected (in red) deselect it
                TextView textViewCheck = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(0);
                if(selection && textViewCheck.getText().toString().equals(selectedBook.getName()))
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(i);
                        textView.setBackground(gd);
                    }
                    //Disable add and modify buttons when row is deselected
                    modifyBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    deleteBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    selection = false;
                    selectedBook = null;
                }
                //If the row is not in red check if there is already a selected row
                else
                {
                    if(selection)
                    {
                        String message = "Please select only one";
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            TextView textView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(i);
                            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        //Enable add and modify buttons when row is selected
                        modifyBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        deleteBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        TextView nameView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(0);
                        selectedBook = storage.findBook(nameView.getText().toString());
                        selection = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //Set row parameters
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableRowParams.setMargins(0,1,0,1);
        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

This is my onCreate

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.books_fragment,container,false);
    storage = InternalStorage.getInstance(this.getContext());
    final Button modifyBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.modifyBtn);
    final Button deleteBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    //Disable modify and delete buttons
    modifyBtn.setEnabled(false);
    deleteBtn.setEnabled(false);
    this.initializeBookTable(storage.getBookList(),view, modifyBtn, deleteBtn);
    Button addBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddModifyBook.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    modifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddModifyBook.class);
            //Passing the selected book to the AddModifyBook activity
            intent.putExtra("selectedBook",selectedBook);
            startActivity(intent);
            selectedBook = null;
            selection = false;
        }
    });
    final TableLayout table = view.findViewById(R.id.book_tableLayout);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            storage.removeBook(selectedBook);
            selectedBook = null;
            selection = false;
            modifyBtn.setEnabled(false);
            deleteBtn.setEnabled(false);
            table.removeView(selectedRow);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

And for onResume I have the default.
Another thing that is happening is that if I just set the background of the name (the first column) with the gradient drawable gd then it works but If I set the rest background of the rest of the columns then I have the problem that I have already explained.

Comment: Please post your `onCreate` and `onResume` function.

Comment: There you go, done

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I have managed to solve the issue by using a gradient drawable for the name and a different gradient drawable for the other properties.